# How to Receive Push Notification on website using Parse JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push, parse-server

I have configured push notifications on Parse-Server & in Android app. But I am not able receive push notifications in a website using Parse JS SDK. They don't provide any method to subscribe for push notifications in ther [JS APIs](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Push.html). There Documentation (JS) only talks about subscribing to mobile devices not browsers.

> SUBSCRIBING TO CHANNELS
>
> The JavaScript SDK does not currently support subscribing iOS and Android devices for pushes. Take a look at the iOS, Android or REST Push guide using the platform toggle at the top.

So, I concluded that web browsers can't subscribe just by using Parse JS SDK? So, **how should I subscribe & receive Push notifications on a web browser from Parse Backend?**

**Update:**

I haven't test but If I use `ServiceWorker` to get subscription & subscribe user to some channel, can I use the default Parse Class `Installation` for saving subscription & then use that **(web) Installation** in Cloud Code to send Push?

Comment: SO has become pretty cool nowadays, half a day of waiting to get answer of a well crafted question & all you get is a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it and got achieved desired results via following. As Jake said, for web there are no Installations in Parse. So, in order to receive push notifications on the web, you have to

1. Register a Service worker to get `pushSubscription` and hande `push`, `click` events etc.
2. Save `pushSubscription` to server. It will be used to send pushes to Web.
3. Integrate Push notifications on Parse-Server (FCM etc) or [`web-push`](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) if you want.
4. Send push via Client SDK or Cloud Code, it must be received.

**Further, the `Installation` class cannot be used for web pushes.**

Comment: It would help if you had any kind of demo or github repo for this.

Answer (score 1):

Parse-Server only supports iOS and Android push notifications. It doesn't even handle web sessions conveniently. There are no Installations for web, because you don't install things for web. There are Sessions, but those don't do anything for Push.